# Python Multiprocessing not working (Discord.py + Windows 10)

Tags: windows, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing, discord, discord.py

The following code does not initiate, the pool or process method. Please help.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild is not None:
        if (message.content.startswith('%season15')):
            input = str(message.content[len('%season15'):].strip())
            df = get_data(input) ##this line of code is processed
            p = Pool(processes=3)
            result = p.starmap(get_season_data, [(input,df,5),(input,df, 10),(input,df,15)])
            processes = [Process(target=get_season_data, args=(symbol, df, i)) for i in [5,10,15]]
            # Run processes
            for p in processes:
                p.start()
            # Exit the completed processes
            for p in processes:
                p.join()
client.run('token#')
```

The code does initiate multiple python processes in task manager but does not process any of the code in get_season_data and does not throw any errors.

Comment: do you need to indent from `@client.event` to `p.join()`?

Comment: Yes @client.event and async def are intended. Sorry about that missed that earlier when posting. I've edited the post above